# Display specific parts of an array ? [SwiftUI]

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I have an empty array `var choosenData = [Choosen]()`
By tapping a button, I append myView() component inside this array (component stored in another array)

```
self.choosenstore.choosenarray.append(
    Choosen(value: self.collectionarray[index].value)
)
```

And I would like to display this array like this:

```
HStack {
    ForEach(choosenstore.choosenarray) { choosen in
        myView(myValue: choosen.value)

    }
}
```

But on multiple lines. I tried multiple solution I saw on StackOverflow and other but it didn't work. 
So maybe is it possible to like do a `"ForEach(choosenstore.choosenarray between 0 and 4 )"` then a `"ForEach(choosenstore.choosenarray between 4 and 8 )"` ect... ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array. So you can deal with it like a normal array in Swift. Something like:

```
    HStack {
        ForEach(
            choosenstore.choosenarray
                .enumerated()
                .filter { (4...8).contains($0.offset) } // Here is the filter for being between 4 and 8
                .map { $1 }) { choosen in
            myView(myValue: choosen.value)
        }
    }
```